# How can I change an elasticbeanstalk environment vpc?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-vpc

I can't seem to find any documentation on this. How do I go about changing the VPC for an elasticbeanstalk environment? I have tried changing the security group from the current group to a group in the new VPC, but amazon returns the following error:

```
SecurityGroups: Invalid option value: 'sg-a91f43d2' (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration', OptionName: 'SecurityGroups'): The security group 'sg-a91f43d2' does not exist
```

The rule does exist, so I assume it is complaining because the rule is in a different VPC (which is the whole point).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.vpc.html#environments-cfg-vpc-console-vpc), you can only change the VPC setting while creating the environment.

> VPC: Choose a VPC for your environment. You can only change this setting during environment creation.